# External Stylesheet not available to plugin when $(window).load fires

Tags: jquery, stylesheet, onload, gsap

> Although this example works fine here , when I break it down to where the css is in an external style sheet, it can't find the css (PLEASE SEE THE COMMENTED OUT EXAMPLE AFTER THE HTML TAGS in the code snippet, the code snippet here works fine b/c the css evaulates to an internal stylesheet). I am using a window.onload event which should wait for DOM, JavaScript, AND the EXTERNAL CSS to load. Why it can't find an external css is my question. While a Greensock experience may help your comfort level with this question, I am pretty sure this is the inability of my greensock plugin to find the external css resource by the time window.onload fires.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
   alert("window is loaded");   
alert("CSSRulePlugin" + CSSRulePlugin);   
    var rule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(".navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:before"); //get the rule
    alert("rule = " + rule);
    
  TweenMax.set(rule, {cssRule:{scaleX:0}});
 });
```

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:before {
    background-color: #000000;
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/plugins/CSSRulePlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="TweenMax.min.js"></script>
 <script src="CSSRulePlugin.min.js"></script>
 
  </head>
<body>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
     
    
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
        <div id="box">

        <ul  id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Something else here</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>          
        </ul>
     
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

    
        

  </body>


  <script> 
 
 
 
</script>

  
</html>
<!-- *** THIS FAILS AS AN EXTERNAL STYLE SHEET, THE CSS IS NOT AVAILABLE TO THE HTML ONLOAD , WHY???????????
/*INDEX.HTML*/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="CSSRulePlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
 
 
   </div>
 
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
     <div id="box">
 
     <ul  id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a></li>
       <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Something else here</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>        
     </ul>
 
 </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>
 
 
 
 
  </body>
 
  <script> 
$(window).load(function() {
alert("window is loaded");
var rule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(".navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:before"); //get the rule
TweenMax.set(rule, {cssRule:{scaleX:0}});
});
</script>
 
 
</html>
 
/*MAIN.CSS*/
 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:before {
    background-color: #000000;
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}


-->
```

Comment: I think this is very difficult to debug to be honest because as you said, it does load up here inside a code snippet. Not really sure what to advice other than look into `console` (present inside the developer tools) for any errors you may have received whilst testing locally.

Comment: I have confirmed that the external stylesheet is indeed the problem in a greensock forum. Thanks for taking the time to view the question. Not sure if this is is a greensock problem or not, but I have posted on their forums. Thanks for your time.